# Отзывчивость в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Как сделать респонсивным tabWidget в PyQt5, чтобы его размеры  всегда были приблизительно равными размерам окна приложения?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTabBar, QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, \
    QTabWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow


class TabBar(QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        size = QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        w = int(self.width()/self.count())
        return QSize(w, size.height())


class Container(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(Container, self).__init__()

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.button = QPushButton(text)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.button)


class CustomWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.tabNum = 3
        self.button = QPushButton("Add tab")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabBar(TabBar())
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.setMovable(True)
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.setElideMode(Qt.ElideRight)
        self.tabs.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab)

        self.tabs.addTab(Container("Very big titleeeeeeeeee"),
                         "Hello World")
        self.tabs.addTab(Container("Tab 1"), "Tab 1")
        self.tabs.addTab(Container("Tab 2"), "Tab 2")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

        vbox.addWidget(self.tabs)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)

    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabs.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        text = f'Tab {self.tabNum}'
        self.tabs.addTab(Container(text), text)
        self.tabNum += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    app.setStyleSheet("""
        QTabBar::tab:selected {
            background: gray;
            color: white;
        }
    """)
    window = CustomWidget() 
    window.resize(600, 600)
    window.show()                         
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Данила ответьте пожалуйста отвечает ли мой ответ на ваш вопрос ?